# inserting a pdf file in the beginning in xelatex

Tags: xetex, pdf

I was creating a book using XeLateX. I've got a front page created by someone else which is in pdf format. Now my question is how can I insert the pdf file to the beginning? I have done this in LaTeX using

```
\includepdf[noautoscale]{frontcover}
```

using the `pdfpages` package. but I'm unable to do so with XeLaTeX. Any pointers?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A simple test works; would you please add a minimal version of what you're doing?

Comment: Hello personally speaking I often use pdfpages with xelatex. Did you include \usepackage{pdfpages} ? Or otherwise do you have only issue to put a PDF at the front cover or anywhere. By the way, as egreg suggested a minimal example would be great to understand your issue... Thanks

Comment: I get some .sty files missing error when I use pdfpages in xetex. :(

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be to compile the document without the front cover and then prepend it later. There are various programs that can modify PDF documents in this way, for example [Pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). You might need to adjust the page counter in LaTeX to get the page numbers right.